# An identity map which is not null-homotopic

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I have some problems in understanding how the definition of a null-homotopic cochain map actually works. Maybe I lack concrete examples.

Let $f^{.}:X^{.}\longrightarrow Y^{.}$ a cochain map of cochain complexes over an abelian category. I say that $f^{.}$ is null-homotopic if there exists a family $\{s^n:X^n \to Y^{n-1}\}_{n}$ of morphisms in the abelian category such that $f^n= d_{Y}^{n-1}s^n + s^{n+1}d^{n}_{X}$ for any $n$.

How can I apply this definition in order to show that the identity map of the complex

$$...\to \frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{4 \mathbb{Z} } \to \frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{4 \mathbb{Z} } \to \frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{4 \mathbb{Z} } \to \frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{4 \mathbb{Z} } \to \frac{ \mathbb{Z} }{4 \mathbb{Z} } \to ...,$$

(with differentials given by the multiplications x$2$), is not null-homotopic?

Comment: Try writing down what $d^{n-1}s^n+s^{n+1}d^n$ is in your example, for an arbitrary pair of maps $s^n$ and $s^{n+1}$

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought that, if the identity cochain map of the complex $X^.$ was null-homotopic, then i could write any element $\bar x \in \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{4\mathbb{Z}}$ as 
$$ \bar x = 2s^n(x)+s^{n+1}(2x)=2(s^n(x)+s^{n+1}(x))$$
which is impossible taking, for example, $\bar x = \bar3$. 

Is there any more elegant and less naive way (if mine is correct!) to see this?

Comment: That's correct, and is the best way to prove it that I can see.  There might be more sophisticated ways of seeing it, but I think ultimately they would be just dressing up the same calculation in fancier langauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer has been discussed in the comments.  Since in your example the $d^n$s are all multiplication by $2$, you are looking for maps $s^n$ and $s^{n+1}$ such that $$x=2s^n(x)+s^{n+1}(2x)=2(s^n(x)+s^{n+1}(x))$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.  But this is impossible, since not every $x\in\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible by $2$.